# browseVignettes not returning anything for ggplot2 package in R - No error message

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

I'm very new to R and recently installed R-studio. I'm trying to familiarize myself with packages by using `browseVignettes()` but it isn't returning anything for the package `ggplot2`, which I know contains vignettes from a tutorial video.

When I try using `browseVignettes` with certain packages in the system library, I receive an error message, e.g.:

```
> browseVignettes("stats")
No vignettes found by browseVignettes("stats")
```

By contrast, I receive no error message when attempting to access the vignettes of `ggplot2`.

My theory is that I installed the package incorrectly. When I went through the installation, I received the below message.

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/micha/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4015425 bytes (3.8 MB)
downloaded 3.8 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyYnCz3\downloaded_packages
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated, as I am hoping to be able to review these vignettes and avoid this error repeating itself next time I install a package from CRAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to R. There is a bit of a learning curve, but it is very powerful once you get the hang of it.

The installation of `ggplot2` looks like it went according to plan. One way to check is to run `library(ggplot2)` in the console. If you do not get an error then it is installed correctly.

`browseVignettes("ggplot2")` should open a browser window with a list of the available vignettes (only 3 in this case). It does so silently, so that is why you did not get a message–error or otherwise.

Not all packages have vignettes, as you have already discovered with the "stats" package.

Comment: Thank you Claus.  I was not aware that `browseVignettes` should open a browser window. In my case, no browser window appears to have been opened.

I've been able to find the vignettes in the R documentation, but it would be useful to be able to access these directly from the console, since I imagine I will need to review a number of packages as I familiarize myself with R and R Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this looking for the answer...

Have you ever seen the term smart quotes as opposed to straight quotes?

It's the "" used in the original, they are smart quotes (curved). Delete them and re-add them in R. Where ever they are being copied from they are not coming into R as straight quotes, thus they are not recognized.

Once they have been changed to straight quotes the command will run.

Hope this helps those coming after....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RStudio (Posit) Cloud, running this function on the Posit Cloud server may lead to a page where the linked contents do not exist. If this is the case, downloading the RStudio Desktop version and running the same browseVignette() functions as above will open a new browser tab with the HTML, source, and R code links leading to the vignettes, and these vignette description pages will be functional.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).